# playing A guitar - is wrong, but why? how does it sound to an Eng.speaker?

Tags: meaning, grammar, articles

I've done my small research on StackExchange and (I think) I realised a subtle difference between:

1. playing THE guitar (usually means playing for yourself, on leisure)

and

2. playing guitar (usually implies being a part of a band or orchestra)

I also know that it is wrong to say "playing A guitar". But why? How does it feel/sound to an English speaker? Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I can't see anything wrong with "playing a guitar": take the sentence "Goodness me, why are you playing a guitar?" or "Do I look cool playing a guitar?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Playing a guitar" means playing a single unspecified guitar. So it would be ok to say "Yesterday at the bar, I drank a beer and played a guitar" to suggest that you found a specific guitar there to play. But it would be a bit odd to say "In my spare time, I play a guitar", as that again suggests that there is one guitar that you play. It would be similar to saying "In my spare time, I play my guitar" but vaguer for no clear reason.

The definite article, meanwhile, is used not just to reference a specific instance but to generalise an entire class. So "I play the guitar" essentially means I play any guitar.

Comment: did I undestand you correctly, that "the" (which usually means a certain item) and "a" (which used to convey an unspecific reference to a class) in case of playing the musical instrument is totally vice-versa?

Comment: No, not because they're musical instruments. Because that's how _play_ works with musical instrument objects. Note that present tense action verbs are normally generic, and refer to repeated or customary actions, not to actual events. "Playing the guitar" is a skill, while "playing a guitar" is an action. "Playing guitar" may mean either, or it can refer to filling a slot in a band or orchestra. And you shouldn't be surprised that definite and indefinite articles aren't always definite or indefinite. There aren't any general rules for articles; they're all idiomatic.

Comment: thank you, but it somehow became less clear :D
why use articles in English then (non necessarily in this context, just in general) ?

Comment: @Hiwi9012 you're right that "the" usually means a specific reference to an item (and it could be used that way here too if there was a specific guitar you wanted to refer to). However "a" doesn't usually mean an unspecific reference to a *class;* it usually refers to an unspecific *item*. The generic sense of "a" is typically used only in definitions ("a guitar is a musical instrument"); it cannot be used as a class reference in general.

Comment: thank you for help